# How to sum multiple field in one field in sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got much code in the input, this code has a parent

```
SELECT [fromAccCode]= 
CASE WHEN [fromAccCode] IN (201010, 201020, 201442, 201521, 201611,201612,209050,
209060,209090,209110,213040,213163,213165,213166,213190) THEN r1
WHEN [fromAccCode] IN (201040, 201048, 201050, 201090, 201120, 201150
,201155) THEN r2
WHEN [fromAccCode] IN (201443,206020,207010,207040,207100,207130,209612
) THEN r3
```

and I set input with this code

```
SELECT [fromAccCode] FROM [dbo].[source_table] WHERE ','+'201010, 
201020,259861,754265,213040,213163,213165,201040,
201048, 201050,201443,206020'+',' like '%,'+cast([fromAccCode] 
AS varchar(10))+',%'
```

I want you have `3` records `1,2,3` form `sum` of values(`r1`), sum of values(`r2`) and sum of values(`r3`) and this fields have values

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve, please have a look here: (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). By the way, in your first query it is missing the table and the format makes it difficult to read. Also include DDL and a short example with source data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first : add one field to set number of case

```
  select  [fromAccCode], --your code
field_name=  --add this code
          CASE 
      WHEN [fromAccCode] IN (201010,201020,201442,201521,201611,201612,209050,209060,209090,209110,213040,213163,213165,213166,213190) THEN 'r1         
      WHEN [fromAccCode] IN (201040,201048,201050,201090,201120,201150,201155) THEN r2
      WHEN [fromAccCode] IN (201443,206020,207010,207040,207100,207130,209612) THEN r3     
               ELSE null
          END
```

You do not need this code snippet :

```
WHERE ',' + '201010,201020,259861,754265,213040,213163,213165,201040,201048,201050,201443,206020' + ',' 
  LIKE CONCAT('%,', [fromAccCode], ',%')
```

Because you have the fromAccCode value

second :

```
 select [fromAccCode ]
  ,[field_name]
  ,sum([value])
   from #result_table  group by [fromAccCode ]
  ,[field_name]
  ,[value]
```

Answer (score 1):

Originally I assumed you could split the WHEN's then SUM them.

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN [fromAccCode] IN (201010, 201020, 201442, 201521, 201611, 201612, 209050, 209060, 209090, 209110, 213040, 213163, 213165, 213166, 213190) THEN r1 END) AS TotalR1,
SUM(CASE WHEN [fromAccCode] IN (201040, 201048, 201050, 201090, 201120, 201150, 201155) THEN r2 END) AS TotalR2,
SUM(CASE WHEN [fromAccCode] IN (201443, 206020, 207010, 207040, 207100, 207130, 209612) THEN r3 END) AS TotalR3
FROM [dbo].[source_table]
WHERE [fromAccCode] IN (
  201010, 201020, 201442, 201521, 201611, 201612, 209050, 209060, 209090, 209110, 213040, 213163, 213165, 213166, 213190,
  201040, 201048, 201050, 201090, 201120, 201150, 201155,
  201443, 206020, 207010, 207040, 207100, 207130, 209612);
```

But it seems that you were looking for something like this monstrosity.

```
SELECT src.fromAccCode,
(CASE 
 WHEN ref.TypeR = 1 THEN src.r1
 WHEN ref.TypeR = 2 THEN src.r2
 WHEN ref.TypeR = 3 THEN src.r3 
 END) AS rx,
SUM([value]) as SumValues
FROM [dbo].[source_table] as src
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT fromAccCode, TypeR FROM (VALUES 
 (201010,1), (201020,1), (201442,1), (201521,1), (201611,1), (201612,1), (209050,1), (209060,1), (209090,1), (209110,1), 
 (213040,1), (213163,1), (213165,1), (213166,1), (213190,1),
 (201040,2), (201048,2), (201050,2), (201090,2), (201120,2), (201150,2), (201155,2),
 (201443,3), (206020,3), (207010,3), (207040,3), (207100,3), (207130,3), (209612,3)
) val (fromAccCode, TypeR)) AS ref ON ref.fromAccCode = src.fromAccCode
GROUP BY src.fromAccCode,
(CASE 
 WHEN ref.TypeR = 1 THEN src.r1
 WHEN ref.TypeR = 2 THEN src.r2
 WHEN ref.TypeR = 3 THEN src.r3 
 END);
```

Btw, about that LIKE criteria.
Using a CONCAT instead of cast to a varchar also works.

```
WHERE ',' + '201010,201020,259861,754265,213040,213163,213165,201040,201048,201050,201443,206020' + ',' 
      LIKE CONCAT('%,', [fromAccCode], ',%')
```

Comment: I guess my interpretation of what you needed wasn't correct then.  Oh well.

Comment: Your description was very good. I did not describe it well,i'm sorry